# What are the most obscure or advanced mathematics with practical application

Tags: soft-question, big-list, applications

Throughout my engineering studies there were jokes made by my professors (mostly mathematics professors) that referenced the fact that pure mathematicians strive to create mathematics with no practical application.  Then a physicist or engineer comes along and finds a use for it.

I know that advancements have been developed for String Theory (maybe the only useful thing to come out of String Theory). But, in that vein, what are some of the most advanced or obscure mathematics that have real world, practical application to engineering, economics, computer science or such (especially if they are not well known)?  And what branch of mathematics do they belong to?

Comment: That your cell phone uses a fractal as the antenna and that that is the optimal choice.\

Comment: I am skeptical of your claim that string theory is a "practical application". But if you believe it is, then current research in topology, algebraic geometry, differential geometry, etc has ties with it.

Comment: Let me clarify on String Theory.  I'm not saying String Theory is practical -- it really seems to be of no practical value.  BUT, I've learned that some of the mathematics developed for it may have practical value outside of String Theory.

Comment: What is obscure mathematics ?

Comment: @Moo The cell phone thing would make a good answer. Please consider submitting it as one.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, Somewhat subject to interpretation, but I would have considered Algebraic Topology and Group Theory to be obscure prior to discoveries for their practical uses.  Most, if not all, applied mathematics started off as theory, so I'd say pure mathematics that only a small number of people know constitutes 'obscure'.  I would distinguish obscure from advanced in that, in my view, advanced takes a well established branch of mathematics and extends it whereas obscure might be an entirely new branch of mathematics.

Comment: I vote for that crazy noneuclidean minkowski geometry stuff that they use to predict the relativistic time skew of GPS satellites.

Comment: First, the premise that "pure mathematicians strive to create mathematics with no practical application" is just a cutesy traditional joke or mythology: don't get sucked into believing it. Second, that mythical process of "physicist or engineer coming along and finding a use for it" is comparably bogus. People just don't operate in quite such a caricatured manner. Also, the idea that there is a fantasy Platonic world in which one could do math apart from the actual physical world is a bit of a stretch, considering that we reside here. Math is the human attempt to resolve puzzles and confusion.

Comment: ... of course, when academic math, like anything else, gets _commodified_, then its original purposes and its possible genuine on-going purposes can get lost in the hustle to make money, get grants, impress people, impress engineering students with the alleged dysfunction of mathematics, and so on.

Comment: I voted to reopen because even though the premises of the question are (the usual) stereotyping and defeatist mythology, I'd wager that many other sincere people would have the same question(s)... if only because the same sort of stereotype-promoting, caricaturizing, bad-scholar "professors" are to be easily found many places. ... sure, I know, it's the general human tendency to find a target for ridicule, which does create a feeling of bonding in the non-targeted group, etc. But, still, srsly, ppl, ...

Comment: 1. An article I saw in Scientific American  about how a topological result informally called the Hairy Ball Theorem was used to explain how certain conditions could result in heart fibrillation...2. Some  solutions to  the most efficient (densest) way to pack congruent non-overlapping hyperspheres in higher-dimensional Euclidean spaces have found application in designing error-correcting codes.  3. The use of Number Theory in  cryptography, which is of no practical use without computers.  4. Hilbert Space theory was developed  well before Quantum Mechanics, where it is indispensable.

Answer (score 5):

A good candidate would be [elliptic curve cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography).

This is a direct practical application of finite fields, number theory, and other arithmetic geometry, that you would otherwise think have no purpose outside of pure mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

I would actually go with the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$. They form a 4 dimensional, associative division algebra. With the basis $i, j , k, 1$ which satisfies
$$ i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = -1 $$

They first might seem not useful at all, until you notice they are easily created with matrices, what means they are easily computable.

Quaternions are used to compute three dimensional rotations and thus are used in many (graphical) software frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a bit obscure -- [finite topological spaces applied to digital analysis](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22finite+topology%22+digital+analysis)

Perhaps a bit advanced -- [spectral sequences applied to physics](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spectral+sequences%22+physics)